# How to get a Linkedin Autofill Generator plugin that runs on a website?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, autofill

I'm trying to add an Autofill Generator from Linkedin in my form.

First, I'm using a button "sign in with linkedin" into my form and then I have added a script for the autofill.js

My button "sign in with linkedin" is working but the button to filling the form with informations from Linkedin doesn't display.

Here is my code :

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="contactForm">
 <div class="line">
  <div class="formItem"><input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME" placeholder="Firstname *" required /></div>
  <div class="formItem formR"> <input type="text" name="LASTNAME"  placeholder="Lastname *" required /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="line">
  <div class="formItem"><input type="text" name="COMPANY_NAME" placeholder="Company *" required /></div>
  <div class="formItem formR"><input type="email" name="MAIL" id="EMAIL" placeholder="Email *" required /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="line">
  <div class="formItem"><input type="text" name="PHONE" id="PHONE" placeholder="Phone *" required /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="line">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: [my_api_key]
authorize: true
</script>
<script type="in/Login"></script>
<script src="https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/js/autofill.js" type="text/javascript" async></script><script type="IN/Form2" data-form="contactForm" data-field-firstname="FIRSTNAME" data-field-lastname="LASTNAME" data-field-phone="PHONE" data-field-email="EMAIL" data-field-company="COMPANY_NAME"></script>
```

I don't know if there's a special condition to use for the Autofill Generator or if I have to add something in my app,..

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you very much for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the support of Linkedin send me here to find answers of my problem, I restart my question if anybody could have an idea.

I need to add a Linkedin Autofill Generator in my form on a website created via **Selligent**, so here step by step what I did :

- I have created an app and have filled the informations required for it (email, url, ..)
- Then when my app was created, I have added two URL in OAuth 2.0 and 2 URL for domain SDK
- Concerning the integration, it's the code in my previous post.

But, when I checked my console, I see this following error message : Load denied by X-Frame-Options: [deleted link] does not permit cross-origin framing.

[here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neVGe.png)

Is there something else to whitelist ? Error in my code ?

Thank you very much !